# Background color у кнопки

Tags: css, button, background-color

[image: Как сделать такую же кнопку?]

Ребята сори я нуб, но как сделать такой же бэкграунд у кнопки? Чтобы выезжал за пределы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать псевдоэлемент и сместить его, например так.

```css
.shift {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.shift::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.25);
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.shift > span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<button class="shift"><span>Уехал</span></button>
```

Comment: Гений. Спасибо!